# Process a set of files from a source directory to a destination directory in Python

Tags: python, path

Being *completely new* in python I'm trying to run a command over a set of files in python. The command requires both source and destination file (I'm actually using imagemagick `convert` as in the example below).

I can supply both source and destination directories, however I can't figure out how to easily retain the directory structure from the source to the destination directory.

E.g. say the `srcdir` contains the following:

```
srcdir/
   file1
   file3
   dir1/
       file1
       file2
```

Then I want the program to create the following destination files on `destdir`: `destdir/file1`, `destdir/file3`, `destdir/dir1/file1` and `destdir/dir1/file2`

So far this is what I came up with:

```
import os
from subprocess import call

srcdir = os.curdir # just use the current directory
destdir = 'path/to/destination'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcdir):
    for filename in files:
        sourceFile = os.path.join(root, filename)
        destFile = '???'
        cmd = "convert %s -resize 50%% %s" % (sourceFile, destFile)
        call(cmd, shell=True)
```

The walk method doesn't directly provide what directory the file is under `srcdir` other than concatenating the root directory string with the file name. Is there some easy way to get the destination file, or do I have to do some string manipulation in order to do this?

Comment: You say "get the destination file", but it's not obvious to me what you want the destination filename + path to be. Please could you elaborate? Are you wanting to preserve the directory structure relative to `srcdir` and `destdir`?

Answer (score 2):

Change your loop to:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcdir):
    destroot = os.path.join(destdir, root[len(srcdir):])
    for adir in dirs:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(destroot, adir))
    for filename in files:
        sourceFile = os.path.join(root, filename)
        destFile = os.path.join(destroot, filename)
        processFile(sourceFile, destFile)
```

Comment: This potentially has the same problem that I pointed out for SilentGhost's answer -- e.g., if srcdir is "foo/bar", then root will be "foo/bar/baz", so "root[len(srcdir):]" will be "/baz".  When you do an os.path.join, and the second argument is an absolute path (which "/baz" is, at least on unix), it will just discard the destdir portion; so you'll end up with destroot="/baz".

Comment: replace `root[len(srcdir):]` by `root[len(srcdir)+len(os.sep):]`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few relative path scripts out there that will do what you want -- namely find the relative path between two paths.  E.g.:

- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/pathutils.html
  **(relpath method)**
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302594-another-relative-filepath-script/
- http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/390d8d3e3ac8ef44/d8c74f96468c6a36?q=relative+path&rnum=1&pli=1

Unfortunately, I don't think this functionality has ever been added to core python.

Answer (score 0):

While not pretty, this will preserve the directory structure of the tree:

```
_, _, subdirs = root.partition(srcdir)
destfile = os.path.join(destdir, subdirs[1:], filename)
```

Comment: You need to be careful here -- you might end up with a "subdirs" string which begins with '/' or '\', which will make os.path.join treat it as an absolute path, throwing away the destdir part of the expression.  If you know what OS you're on, it's fairly easy to work around that, though.

Comment: @Edward: that's why I do slicing, no?

Comment: replace `subdirs[:1]` by `subdirs.lstrip(os.sep)`