# download a folder of files given the http url of the files directory with python

Tags: python, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looping through a directory on the web and displaying its contents (files and other directories) via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907728/looping-through-a-directory-on-the-web-and-displaying-its-contents-files-and-oth)

hi, Guys,

If I have code files under

http://AAA/BBB/tags/revision/

how can I download these files in python?

and If they have 600M in total, is there some efficient way to do it?

Comment: 1.  Please search for the existing answers to this question.  2.  Please read about `urllib2`.  3.  Please show how this question isn't a total duplicate.

Comment: Hi, S.Lott, thank you for your feedback. Do you mean we need a loop to download the file one by one?

Comment: if you're using a repository is there some reason you can't just use the associated repo client to download what you need?

Comment: hi, yes, I am using the repository. but I need to develop a software which could download these files, instead of using associated repo. tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using svn as your repository? It would look like this:

```
from subprocess import  Popen, PIPE

def svn_co(url):
    return run_program('svn', 'co', url)

def run_program(*args):
    popen_obj = Popen(args, stderr=PIPE)
    _, errors = popen_obj.communicate()
    if popen_obj.returncode:
        print errors

# This will get all the files in myproject's tagged version
# named tagname into the current directory
svn_co('http://svn.myserver.net/myproject/tags/tagname')
```